# Excel graph based on data subset

Tags: excel, graph, filter

I am struggling with Excel to make a graph based on a condition that is not part of the graph. The data set it is based on can't be filtered. It has to be shown in full, but the graph should only contain a subset based on a fixed criterium. For instance: I have 20 rows of data, but only row 3, 9 and 10 meet the criterium. And this changes all the time. Only those three (in this example) have to show up in the graph. I just don't know how to do this. Any thoughts? I'm working with Excel 2010.

I am not sure which other information is useful for you to understand my problem. Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel Formulas to filter the data to another place (maybe a hidden Worksheet) and give that one as the source of the chart.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. What could that formula look like? Do you mean a simple one like If "a certain field"=value, then copy that field, otherwise leave it blank?

Comment: That depends on the data you want to filter, your filtering criteria, and the type of the graph.

Comment: Just some feedback: I got it working using a combination of copying the filtered data to a hidden worksheet, and graphing it using dynamic ranges. Thanks for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score -2):

If your data is in a properly formatted table, you could try a pivot chart.

a) It might be helpful if you could provide sample data and sample output you are trying to achieve?

or,

b) you could add a formula column which evaluates the contents of the data column, e.g. if criteria column = "some value" then data else zero or null (E.G. your criteria column is A, your data column is B, then in column C you could write =IF(A2="Yes",B2,0) or =IF(A2>=5,B2,0)). then you can graph the data in column C?

Comment: I've tried this road. Couldn't get it to work with the type of graph I have. But thank you for the reply!